# Lock on the SQL tables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, locking

Suppose I have a procedure, which is trying to insert records into a separate table one by one based on the condition evaluation and using sys_refcursor I am trying to out that table in which we inserted the data.

Within the procedure we have DML and DDL commands like truncate, insert, select, create cursor.

Suppose, multiple users try to call the procedure using SAME parameters.

Issue is when multi users will try to run the procedure inside which we are truncating the same table in which we are inserting into and selecting from in the end, there is a possibility of data loss or data ambiguity in the output data.

Want to know, whether procedure puts a lock on the tables mentioned within the procedure body.

Right now to out the resultset of the procedure, I am inserting the rows into that tablename and using sys_refcursor, I am returing it's contents using below code:

```
open prc for select * from tablename;
```

Suppose I don't want to insert the rows into any table. I need to directly out the result set from select statement to output variable. How can we achieve this?

does procedure call, puts a lock the tables mentioned within the procedure body, so that no other user can access the tables and modify them.

pseudocode:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME(var1 in VARCHAR2, var2 in NUMBER, prc out SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS 
  cursor c1 IS 
  select v3 from TABLE_NAME1 where v1 = var1 and v2 = var2; 
  begin
   EXECUTE immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE AUDIT_TABLE';
   if (var2 = 2)
    then
     for var3 in c1
      loop
         insert into AUDIT_TABLE select col1,col2,col3,col4 
       from              
       (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by row_id) AS num_row, col1, v2, col2, col3, col4 
       from TABLE_NAME1
       where col3 = var3.v3 and v1 = var1 and v2 = var2) a
       inner join 
       (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by row_id) AS num_row, col1, v2, col2, col3, col4 
       from TABLE_NAME1 
       where col3 = var3.v3 and v1 = var1 and v2 = var2) b on
       (b.num_row = a.num_row + 1)
       inner join TABLE_NAME2 c on (a.v2 = c.v2);
        end loop;
       end if;
  open prc for select * from AUDIT_TABLE;
 end;
```

Comment: DDL on any object should not be done concurrently. Moreover, they should not be done as often as DML: tables are for persistency. Possibly you are trying to emulate temporary table using general table, then you need to change table's type. Possibly as a private temporary table since 18c.

Comment: Agree, look into temporary tables. However, in all likelihood you shouldn't be writing intermediate data to any table of any kind. Why not simply return the cursor for `select * from table` without bothering with the in-between table you've created? Even beyond that, why use a ref cursor at all? Why not just have the calling process query `table1` normally instead of calling a procedure?

Comment: Some basic guidelines: (1) prefer pure SQL over a PL/SQL solution, (2) prefer single-step operations over multiple stages involving temporary data, (3) prefer temporary objects over permanent ones for scratch work, (4) reserve truncate for jobs that only one session can be running, (5) when you have to work with a real table prefer operating on rows rather than on entire tables, (6) keep you transactions short - don't allow the possibility that a transaction may not be committed by a caller. Following these guidelines will help reduce problems with concurrency and locking.

Comment: I need to iterate using loop through cursor to compare two consecutive records for some condition and then insert that record after every comparison. If I will not use any kind of intermediatory table to store, then how can I return all the records which I have gathered one by one using comparison

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what is the purpose of your procedure, maybe there are better solutions. But ...

- Each DML statement is optimized and translated into some kind of "bytecode". - This "bytecode" works with numerical data segment ID, rather than with pure table name.
- TRUNCATE is DDL statement. It discards table's data segment and allocates a new one. In order to truncate a table, there must not be any running cursors depending on table's library cache object. So truncate will wait until **all** DML finish
- In between truncate and insert some other session can truncate the same table. Then you will have two sessions inserting into the same table.
- Although you have two sessions inserting into the same table, they will not interfere. You do not commit transaction(except truncate - DDL always commits). So each session's cursor will return only own sessions data.
- NOTE: your procedure does not COMMIT/ROLLBACK so any consecutive TRUNCATE will have to wait until the 1st call to your procedure decides what to do with its own data.

Comment: `truncate` will not wait for running `select` statement and will cause object no longer exists in that session.

Comment: If multiusers try to call the procedure for the same input values, then the user which called the procedure first will get the lock on the tables involved in procedure???? or every user will have shared lock on the involved tables

Comment: Your code does not use input parameters. Also it is not clear whether you commit your transaction or not. Do you need to preserve any data in your table. Maybe just pure temporary table would suit you better.

Comment: suppose I have a table named TABLE_NAME1, which contains some audit data. I want to showcase the audit data corresponding some values. so I have opened cursor to iterate through each record having that required value. I want to return back the output of the select back to the calling JAVA object. refer below code in which first I am trying to insert the required records into one table and then I am using sys_refcursor to return the result set. can anyone help how can I not insert into intermediatory table and out the result directly